# Zip two list of lists together - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list

There are a few questions on this but none relate to this. I have two separate list of lists that I want to zip together. The comprehension works for a normal list but not a list of lists.

```
X = [[17, 4]]
Y = [[32,-58]]

lst = [list(x) for x in zip(X, Y)]
```

Out:

```
[[[17, 4], [32, -58]]]
```

Intended:

```
[[17, -32], [4, -58]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
lst = [list(x) for x in zip(*(X + Y))]
```

What you want to do is, create a 2D list by merging `X` and `Y` and then transpose it using `zip(*(X+Y))`.

Comment: Thanks @Vasilis G. What does the `*` operator do?

Comment: @jonboy the operator `*` in used in a list of lists in order to unpack values of the outer list and use them as arguments for the `zip` function. In your case: `zip(*(X+Y))` is `zip(*[[17, 4],[32,-58]])` which will unpack the outer list and return `zip([17, 4],[32,-58])`. Then the `zip` function will be applied to those two lists.

Comment: Aww ok. Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this

```
[list(x) for x in zip(*X, *Y)]

Out[222]: [[17, 32], [4, -58]]
```